# Subaru forester electric window motor - part identification

Tags: subaru, power-windows, forester

The front right ( UK drivers side) electric window on my 2004 Forester has never worked, and today I took the motor out to inspect - and it's toast, utterly rotten.

Is it the same as the back one? I know the regulators are different, but are the motors? Is it the same as the pre 2002 models?

New motors seem to go for a fortune on eBay, so I'm hoping I can find either a decent second hand one or a cheaper alternative...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to be contrary to @JoshCaswell, but I'm seeing as how the left front/right rear are the same motor, as is the right front/left rear. Using the numbers he gave, I'm seeing the following as alternate parts numbers:

FL/RR: [61188FE001, 61188FE002, 61188FE021, 61188FE022, 61188SA011, 62113FC100, 62188SA000, 62188SA001, 62188SA002, 63113FC100](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=3472212&cc=1426788&jnid=424&jpid=0)

FR/LR: [61188FE011, 61188FE012, 61188FE031, 61188FE032, 61188SA000, 61188SA001, 62113FC110, 62188SA010, 62188SA011, 62188SA012, 63113FC110](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=3472590&cc=1426788&jnid=424&jpid=1)

Comment: That is interesting. The Subaru part numbers for the four doors' motors are definitely different: Front Right 61188SA001 Rear Right 6**2**188SA001 Rear Left 6**2**188SA0**1**1, but I guess that doesn't mean that they aren't the same piece after all.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - It surprised me as well.

Comment: I've ordered one of those, so I'll update this when it arrives...

Comment: Fitted the new motor yesterday - it fitted and worked perfectly :)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it worked out for you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the parts diagrams and lists on [Opposed Forces](http://opposedforces.com/parts/forester/en_s11/type_22/body_equipment_exterior/door_parts_glass_and_regulator/illustration_1/), you are out of luck as far as using a rear door's motor. Each of the four doors has its own part number; the front right's number is 61188SA001 whereas the front left is 61188SA010.

On the other hand, if you see [the usage list for 61188SA001](http://opposedforces.com/parts/info/61188SA001/), this part seems to have been used on a wide range of S11 vehicles. In the UK/Europe, Foresters built from 2002 to mid-2006 will have this part, as will USDM models from late 2001 through the beginning of 2007.

There is also an alternative part number, [61188SA000](http://opposedforces.com/parts/info/61188SA000/), from earlier Forester models, that will fit.